# bash obtain wc -l number and display in one command?

Tags: bash, count, lines, tee, wc

I'm pretty sure this is going to be obvious, but currently im doing this:

```
count=`find $dir -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
```

This gets me the number i want, but dosen't display anything on screen (although i chuck away error lines anyhow).

Is there a way to do this (obtain the wc -l count into count variable) while also displaying the output to the console, in one command ? I'm pretty sure something like `tee` could be used here, but my brain isn't working like it should.

Otherwise, i guess writing to a temp file and console using `tee` and `cat` it back into `wc` would work, but I'm pretty convinced there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

**edit:** *Sorry, it seems the question was unclear.* I don't want to show the count to screen, i want to show the output that i've been counting, i.e: the output from find

Comment: `tee /dev/tty` should answer your updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, so you want to print the normal output, and have the number of matches in `$count`?

Try this:

```
count=`find $dir -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null | tee /dev/tty | wc -l`
```

Comment: It's the output of find, not the count, that Sirex wanted to see.

Comment: @David Conrad: That's what this does.

Comment: Sorry, you must have been editing it right around the time I was commenting on it. My comment applied to an earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, an answer to the updated question then

The tty approach is nice, but will fail over non-terminals (e.g. ssh localhost 'echo hello > /dev/tty' fails)

It could just be

```
count=`find $dir -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null | tee >(cat >&2) | wc -l`
```

Which is equivalent to

```
count=`find $dir -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null | tee /proc/self/fd/2 | wc -l`
```

If you don't want to/cannot use stderror (fd 2) as the sidechannel here, then you can open a duplicate of the original stdout and refer to it instead:

```
exec 3>&1
count=`find $dir -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null | tee /proc/self/fd/3 | wc -l`
```

$0.02

Comment: I like this one. I was trying to remember how to open a duplicate of an existing file handle, and couldn't remember.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** I [have added another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563491/bash-obtain-wc-l-number-and-display-in-one-command/5564112#5564112) after the question had been updated

```
unset x
echo ${x:="$(find $dir -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null | wc -l)"}
echo $x
```

output

```
16
16
```

Comment: @Paul: really... well I thought the question was about setting the variable while showing it; but i updated the answer for the bleedingly obvious :)

Comment: Why does this have two upvotes when it doesn't even answer the question? Sirex wanted it to output the results of find, not the count.

Comment: Indeed, [have posted a new answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563491/bash-obtain-wc-l-number-and-display-in-one-command/5564112#5564112) now

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to your clarified question. This puts the count in variable $count and shows the output of find:

```
found=$(find $dir type f \( -perm -007 \) -print 2>/dev/null)
count=$(echo -e "$found" | wc -l)
echo -e "$found"
```

Comment: @Sirex: Easy come, easy go ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand, since the find command, as written, doesn't need the parentheses and shouldn't produce any errors, and I don't know if you need to have the output go to stdout or if you just want to see it working, in which case stderr would work just as well. I would do this:

```
count=`find $dir -type f -perm -007 -print -fprint /dev/stderr | wc -l`
```

Comment: i'm discarding permission denied errors which sometimes occur when this isnt run as root, at least i think i am :)

Comment: Ah. Mine will end up with the permission denied errors still shown, then. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the output of find to screen, if you `tee` the stdout of the find command to stderr (here via an anonymous fifo).

If your file names or paths have embedded newlines, your count will go awry. Therefore, use the -print0 feature of find, then delete all bytes that are **not** '\0' with the tr command, and finally just count the '\0' bytes with the wc command at the very end.

```
# show output of find to screen
count=`find . -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print0 2>/dev/null | tee >(tr '\0' '\n' > /dev/stderr) | tr -dc '\0' |  wc -c`
echo "$count"

# show output of count to screen
count=`find . -type f \( -perm -007 \) -print0 2>/dev/null | tee >(tr -dc '\0' | wc -c > /dev/stderr) | tr -dc '\0' |  wc -c`
echo "$count"
```